# Coupon collector problem for collecting set k times.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, coupon-collector

Recently I tried to solve a problem that based on coupons collector problem. Let it be sth like this:

If a package has one of 50 random baseball cards, how many packages do you need to buy to get a complete set? (or sth like this, doesnt matter)

If I need every card one time, so it makes one set that is easy, explaination is on wikipedia and I already understood it. But what if we consider to collect every card k times? (To collect k sets of cards)

How can I tried to solve this problem? I found sth about Chernoff's bound (http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/courses/pg/l10.pdf) but I dont get it actually if it is a solution of this problem. I need to estimate E(X) and Var(X) for k sets of cards.

Could anyone give me a hint how to solve this problem?
Thanks for all answers:)

Greetings,

Comment: The answer is on the Wikipedia page on the Coupon Collector's problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations , where the Newman-Shepp result says that approximately $\Theta(n\log\log n)$ more samples are needed for each additional set.  You should be able to find their AMM article without too much trouble.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki the Wikipedia link gives $O(n \log n)$ not $O(n \log \log n)$ (unless we think of $k$ as a function of $n$...).

Comment: @JohnEngbers Wikipedia says $n\log n+(k-1)n\log\log n$, so I was breaking it down as $n\log n$ for the 'first' (which was the result I presumed the OP already knew) and then $n\log\log n$ for each additional set.

Answer (score 8):

I'm closing some other questions as a duplicate of this one, so I'll collect the information that's been posted in various places in one place:

This problem was treated in the paper [The double Dixie cup problem](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F2308930) by Newman and Shepp. The expected collection time is

$$
n \log n + (m-1) n \log\log n + O(n)\;,
$$

so, as Steven Stanicki noted, each additional set collected takes $n\log\log n$ time.

In [Some new aspects of the coupon collector's problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304229), Myers and Wilf gave a simpler derivation of the result and a generating function in one variable.

The result is also derived in Section $5$ of [The Coupon Collector’s Problem](http://www.mat.uab.cat/matmat/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf) by Ferrante and Saltalamacchia, which treats various generalisations of the coupon collector's problem with various approaches.

The exact formula for the expected collection time given by Newman and Shepp is
$$
n\int_0^\infty\left[1-\left(1-\mathrm e^{-x}{\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{x^i}{i!}}\right)^n\right]\mathrm dx.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It asymptotically almost surely takes $O(n \log n)$ time to collect $n$ cards, so for any constant number of sets it should take (a.a.s.) $O(n \log n)$ time as well, since at worst case you can imagine 'forgetting' to count duplicates until you have a new set.  Therefore you can only hope to improve the constant, unless you are hoping to incorporate the number of sets ($k$) as a variable.

Comment: I think incorporating the number of sets as a variable is the point of the question...

Comment: Yes - your wikipedia link provides the nice formula.

Comment: Thanks for all answers, I think it will be easier to understand for me now. Once again, thanks a lot for all answers!:)