# Markov chains for collector problems

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider the following problem, from Tijms's *Understanding Probability*:

> The Bubble Company offers a picture of one of 25 popstars in
>   a pack of chewing gum. John and Peter each buy one pack every week. They
>   pool the pictures of the popstars. Assuming equal chances of getting any of the
>   25 pictures with one purchase, denote by the random variable $N$ the number
>   of weeks until John and Peter have collected two complete sets of 25 pictures.
>   Calculate the expected value of N and calculate the probability $P (N > n)$ for $n = 50$, 75, 100, 125, and 150.

This problem should be solvable with an absorbing Markov chain.

I define the system to be in the state $(i,j)$ when $j$ popstars have appeared two or more times so far, and $i-j$ popstars have appeared exactly one time.
Clearly, $1\le i\le 25$ and $0\le j\le i$.

The state $(25,25)$ is absorbing, since it corresponds to a completed collection.

The transition probabilities for the non-absorbing states are:
$$
\begin{gathered}
p_{(i,j),(i+1,j)} = \frac{25-i}{25} \\
p_{(i,j),(i,j+1)} = \frac{i-j}{25}  \text{ for } j+1\le i\\
p_{(i,j),(i,j)} = \frac{j}{25} \text{ for } (i,j)\ne(25,25).
\end{gathered}
$$

To solve a problem with some matrix computations,  we need a way to index the states, and a possible choice I guess is:
$$
\text{index}(i,j) = i + 25j - \frac12 (j-1)(j-2).
$$
Then, to answer e.g. the question on the probability $P(N>50)$ I should compute the 99-th power (because there are two draws for every week, and we start with state $(1,0)$ which corresponds with a single draw), but this seems quite complicated for a textbook problem. Also, the matrix is quite large so computing all these matrix products seems expensive.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Some of the references cited in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151267/coupon-collector-problem-for-collecting-set-k-times) may help.  (I don't know, I haven't looked at them yet.)

Comment: Yes indeed.  Look at [The double Dixie-Cup Problem](https://faculty.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Double-dixie-cup-problem.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Double Dixie-Cup" paper that I mentioned in a comment proves that the expected number of packs needed to get $m$ full sets of $n$ pictures is 
$$n\log{n}+(m-1)\log\log{n} +O(n)\text{ as } n\to\infty.$$

That is the first full set "costs" $n\log{n}$, but each additional set costs only $\log\log{n}$.

This gives $25\log{25}+\log\log{25} \approx 81.641$, and since they buy two packs a week, about $41$ weeks.

Since $25$ is a long way from $\infty$, I did a simulation to see what actually happens.  In my model, they make two piles, and the first time they get a picture, they put it in pile A, the second time in pile B.  The third and later times are ignored.

```
from random import choice
from collections import defaultdict

tests = 100000
population = range(25)

weeks = defaultdict(int)
for _ in range(tests):
    A = 25*[0]
    B = 25*[0]
    week = 0
    while sum(B)<25:
        for i in range(2):
            s = choice(population)
            if A[s] == 0:
                A[s] = 1
            elif B[s] == 0:
                B[s] = 1
        week +=1
    weeks[week] += 1

expect = sum(k*weeks[k] for k in weeks)/tests
print(tests, 'trials')
print('Mean number of weeks', expect)
for n in range(50, 175, 25):
    p = sum(weeks[k] for k in weeks if k > n)/tests
    print('Prob of more than %d weeks: %s'%(n,p))
```

This produced the output

```
100000 trials
Mean number of weeks 71.35634
Prob of more than 50 weeks: 0.92788
Prob of more than 75 weeks: 0.3365
Prob of more than 100 weeks: 0.06485
Prob of more than 125 weeks: 0.01089
Prob of more than 150 weeks: 0.0018
```

which is a waiting time about $12.5\%$ shorter than the estimate for large $n$.

Though I haven't read the book, I would guess the author has the theoretical result in mind, but if I'm not mistaken, that actually gives a very poor answer.  Perhaps I do him an injustice, and he means you to do the simulation.  Although the Markov chain method is certainly correct, as you say, it does seem like a lot of calculation.  Still, I may do it, if only to convince myself that I haven't made an error in the simulation.

**EDIT**

I ran the Markov chain calculations today, and they agree very closely with the simulation.

```
import numpy as np

def idx(n,m):
    return n*(n+1)//2+m
states = idx(25,25)+1
P = np.zeros((states, states))
for n in range(26):
    for m in range(n+1):
        s = idx(n,m)       # start state
        sa = idx(n+1, m) # add to pile A
        sb = idx(n, m+1) # add to pile B
        if n==m==25:
            P[s,s] = 1
        elif n ==25:
            P[s,sb] = (25-m)/25
            P[s,s] = m/25
        elif n == m:
            P[s, sa] = (25-n)/25
            P[s,s] = n/25
        else:
            P[s,sa] = (25-n)/25  # card not in pile A
            P[s,sb] = (n-m)/25   # card in pile A, not in pile B
            P[s,s] = m/25           # card in both piles
P=P@P #two cards per week
N=np.linalg.inv(np.eye(states-1)-P[:-1, :-1])
expect= (N@np.ones(states-1))[0]
print('Mean number of weeks', expect)        
P25 = np.linalg.matrix_power(P, 25)
start = np.zeros(states)
start[0] = 1

for n in range(50, 175, 25):
    m = n//25
    Q = np.linalg.matrix_power(P25,m)
    done  = (start@Q)[states-1]
    print('Prob of more than %d weeks: %s'%(n,1-done))
```

produced the output

```
Mean number of weeks 71.43383331673435
Prob of more than 50 weeks: 0.9288061487085777
Prob of more than 75 weeks: 0.33953755904361504
Prob of more than 100 weeks: 0.06481946982508657
Prob of more than 125 weeks: 0.010513629113593548
Prob of more than 150 weeks: 0.0016196726615316237
```

Comment: Thank you, your results agree with the solutions of the book. Also the indexing function is (now) clear, I missed that during my attempt.